# Traveling to Canada with my US tourist visa

Tags: usa, canada, b1-b2-visas

I have a B1/B2 single entry visa to the US. It's valid for five more months.
Can I go to Canada at the end of July to celebrate Eid for a couple days with my families and friends?

The answer may be no, because if I go to Canada, I cannot reenter the US. How can I obtain a  visa to come to back to the United States?

Comment: Unless Canada offers you a visa waiver, please note that you will require a Canadian visitor visa. Yes, I realize this  comment is rather late!

Answer (score 6):

In general, yes, you can - under a process known as "Automatic Revalidation".

In short, Automatic Revalidation allows your existing visit to the US to continue if you have left the US to a neighboring country (ie, Canada or Mexico) and returned - even if your visa is no longer valid (which in effect, yours isn't as you've used your single allowed entry).

There are some specific conditions to using this process, and you should check the relevant pages on both the [US State Department](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/general/automatic-revalidation.html) and the [US CBP](http://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/documents/auto_reva.pdf) websites to confirm you're allowed.

Given the recent removal of I94 forms, I would suggest printing out a copy of your current I94 from the website http://www.cbp.gov/i94 before leaving the US, as well a printing out a copy of the document above from the US CBP website just in case you have any problems when checking in for your flight from Canada to the US.

Obviously depending on your nationality you may also require a visa for Canada.